# Get User custom fields without SOQL (like $User in formulas)?

Tags: apex-code

I have some custom fields on my User object that I want to access with APEX code in my VisualForce trigger. When I access it from a Formula field I get to use a nifty $User reference like this:

```
$User.my_prop__c
```

From APEX I have to query the User object by UserId like this:

```
[select my_prop__c from User where id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].my_prop__c;
```

Is there something baked into APEX already that would let me get at the user properties without the SOQL query? If not, does anyone know of a utility class for lazy loading and caching user properties so the overhead is minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something similar to the following code sample. It uses a singleton pattern to statically store the information in memory for the duration of your transaction. It's similar to the lazy loading that twamley proposed but I feel this is a much simpler approach.

Usage 1: UserUtil.CurrentUser.Email;

Usage 2: User someUser = UserUtil.getUser(someUserId);

This will allow you to access the same information on the current user or other users in the system. Notice the queryUsers method just returns a query result. This makes it easy to add and remove fields from your query as it is isolated in its own method keeping things simple.

Note: that this code pulls in all users when used. Most orgs do not have multiple hundreds of users so heap size shouldn't be a concern. But if it is you can just modify the queryUsers() method to only return active users or filter down based on other criteria.

```
public class UserUtil {
//Protected Members
private static final UserUtil instance = new UserUtil();
private Map<Id, User> mapUsers;

//Properties
public static User CurrentUser {
    get { return getUser(UserInfo.getUserId()); }
}

//Constructor
private UserUtil() {
    mapUsers = new Map<Id, User>(queryUsers());
}

//Public Methods
public static User getUser(Id userId) {
    if (instance.mapUsers.containsKey(userId)) {
        return instance.mapUsers.get(userId);
    }
    else {
        throw new InvalidUserIdException('Unable to locate user id: ' + userId);
    }
}

//Private Methods
private List<User> queryUsers() {
    return [SELECT 
                Id
                , Name
                , UserName
                , Email
                , Alias 
            FROM 
                User];
}

//Internal Classes
public class InvalidUserIdException extends Exception {}
```

}

Comment: Nice work. I like the singleton pattern approach and returning the query result is a nice touch too.

Comment: @john But will it work for the new users ? I think you are querying the user object only once

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own utility class. I'm still interested in better techniques though. 
This utility class lazy loads when the first property is accessed. Update_Closed_Won_Opportunities__c and Set_Opportunities_to_Closed_Won__c are my custom fields on the User object (visible only to System Administrators so people can't upgrade their permissions).

```
public with sharing class MyUserInfo {
    private Id userId;
    private User myUser; // Hold onto the user object once we've loaded it

    // Default constructor uses the active user id
    public MyUserInfo() {
        userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    }

    // Secondary constructor accepts a user id as a parameter
    public MyUserInfo(Id someOtherUserId) {
        userId = someOtherUserId;       
    }

    // Only called one time when we first need it so grab all of the custom fields now
    private void LazyLoadUser() {
        System.AssertNotEquals(null, userId);
        myUser = [
            SELECT Update_Closed_Won_Opportunities__c, Set_Opportunities_To_Closed_Won__c
            FROM User 
            WHERE id = :userId
        ];
        System.AssertNotEquals(null, myUser, 'Unable to load user with id ' + userId); // could return defaults instead
    }

    // Getters (be sure to include each field in the SOQL of LazyLoadUser)
    public boolean UpdateClosedWonOpportunities { get {
        if (myUser == null) LazyLoadUser();
        return myUser.Update_Closed_Won_Opportunities__c;
    } }
    public boolean SetOpportunitiesToClosedWon { get {
        if (myUser == null) LazyLoadUser();
        return myUser.Set_Opportunities_To_Closed_Won__c;
    } }
}
```

Here is my trigger utilizing that class. The first line `myUserInfo = new MyUserInfo();` doesn't run any SOQL. That won't happen until the first custom get property is used. Subsequent calls don't need SOQL.

```
trigger LockClosedOpportunity on Opportunity (before update) {
    MyUserInfo myUserInfo = new MyUserInfo();
    for (Opportunity o : trigger.old)
    {
        if (!myUserInfo.UpdateClosedWonOpportunities && o.StageName == 'Closed Won')
            trigger.newMap.get(o.Id).addError('You do not have permission to change an Opportunity after it has been set to Closed Won.');
    }
    for (Opportunity o : trigger.new)
    {
        if ( !myUserInfo.SetOpportunitiesToClosedWon && o.StageName == 'Closed Won' && trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).StageName != 'Closed Won' )
            o.addError('You do not have permission to set an Opportunity to Closed Won.');
    }
}
```

It reads similar to $User in formulas and I don't have to worry about tacking on multiple SOQL calls when one (or zero) suffices.